# localStorage retrieval / getItem is returning null

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage

I have added a theme switcher to my app that allows me to change theme/variable.scss files via the interface through a on/off switch.

On refresh/navigation I want the users preference to be remembered. I have setItem to local storage and that's showing up in my browsers local storage.

Next, I want to retrieve that choice, if there is local storage available, otherwise keep default theme set.

AppComponent.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  currentTheme: string;
  constructor( @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document) {
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    if (localStorage.length > 0) {
      this.currentTheme = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.localTheme));
    } else {
      this.currentTheme = 'Standard contrast';
      this.document.getElementById('theme').className = 'standard-theme';
    }
  }

  handleThemeChange(event) {
    if (this.currentTheme === 'Standard contrast') {
    this.document.getElementById('theme').className = 'high-contrast-theme';
      this.currentTheme = 'High contrast mode';
    } else {
    this.document.getElementById('theme').className = 'standard-theme';
      this.currentTheme = 'Standard contrast';
    }
    localStorage.setItem('localTheme', this.currentTheme);
  }

}
```

`localStorage.localTheme` returns 'Standard contrast' or 'High contrast mode' as expected - I need this to then update `currentTheme` so the users choice remains on refresh - but when I debug this comes as `null`

UPDATE:

```
this.currentTheme = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.localTheme));
```

This line seems to be the issue, although `(localStorage.localTheme)` returns value `this.currentTheme` = null ?

A little help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: `localStorage.localTheme` was the same as `localStorage.getItem("localTheme")` in previous versions of the Storage API (and persists in some implementations). Use the latter (without `JSON.parse()` in this case) for best compatibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Heretic Monkey was correct with the API update. Hence I got it working with:

```
  ngOnInit() {

    if (localStorage.length > 0) {
      this.currentTheme = localStorage.getItem("localTheme");
      const themeClass = this.currentTheme === 'Standard contrast' ? 'standard-theme' : 'high-contrast-theme';
      this.document.getElementById('theme').className = themeClass;
    } else {
      this.currentTheme = 'Standard contrast';
      this.document.getElementById('theme').className = 'standard-theme';
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

While setting `localTheme` in localstorage, you have set a string, not serialized object.
 So don't parse it

Try:

```
this.currentTheme = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.localTheme);
```

Comment: it was good not to parse - ive kept that but this.currentTheme still comes in null whilst localStorage.localTheme has value

Answer (score 0):

try a getter and setter and access it with `this.localTheme`

```
get localTheme() {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('localTheme'));
}

set localTheme(val) {
    localStorage.setItem('localTheme', JSON.stringify(val));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const currentTheme = this.currentTheme;
localStorage.setItem('localTheme', currentTheme);
```

Also do `console.log(typeof this.currentTheme)` to see what is the type

Comment: It's `typeof`, not `type of` :).